# How to bottom-align both \lfoot and \rfoot together using fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, align, fancyhdr

LaTeX code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lfoot{\Large Hello\\World}
\rfoot{\Large \thepage}
\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsum
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The bottom of `\rfoot` (page number "1") is not aligned with the bottom of `\lfoot` (Hello World). Is there a way to bottom-align both `\lfoot` and `\rfoot`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\fancyfoot` you have access to the entire footer, so you can combine/align things any way you want.  The `\rlap` `\llap` approach allows the left or right section to extend past the midpoint, and helps center the center section (if used).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,footskip=30pt,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{\leavevmode\rlap{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\Large Hello\\World}}%
  \hfill\llap{\Large \thepage}}
\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsum
\end{document}
```